# Mercurial web user authorization

Tags: mercurial, authorization

We installed Mercurial on the server which we use to synchronize developer's local repositories. We use stand alone mercurial web server (hg serve), what we want is to grant access to the web server only to the authorized users, right now it is accessible to all.

Is there any way to configure authorization for Mercurial stand alone web server?

*In the configuration file (hgrc) there is a section called `[auth]` where a list of users can be defined, but it seems it is used for something else, not for web server.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hg serve` allows you to set up *authorization* rules in `[auth]`, but doesn't handle *authentication* on its own. It should be provided by a web server.

You have at least these two options for authentication handling:

1. Configure the [hgweb](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#hgweb) script with Apache, lighttpd, or another web server of your choice.
2. Put `hg serve` behind [nginx](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgServeNginx).

**Edit.** Here's an excerpt from my nginx config file (requests auth for both read and write):

```
location / {
    auth_basic            "hg-server";
    auth_basic_user_file  /path/to/htpasswd/file;
    proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header      REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
}
```

Comment: As I understood it the second option seems simple enough, but only checks for credentials when pushing, we want no unauthorized read access as well.

Comment: @BanditoBunny: No, you simply drop the `limit_except GET` directive. And I also found I have `proxy_set_header` in my config file, guess one actually needs it so the user is forwarded to `hg serve` properly. See my updated answer.

Comment: I need to check your solution, reverse proxy is actually not what i had in mind.